My IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware on Azure Function isn't invokated
I'm trying to implement a middleware for my Azure Functions type HttpRequest, I'm using the IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware interface in  .NET 6:
public class HistoryLogMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
  public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
  {
    var requestData = await context.GetHttpRequestDataAsync();
    var body = await new StreamReader(requestData.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

    Console.WriteLine($"Request Body: {body}");

    await next(context);

    var responseData =  context.GetHttpResponseData().Body;
    var resp = await new StreamReader(responseData).ReadToEndAsync();

    Console.WriteLine($"Response: {resp}");
  }
}

In my startup class, I have this code:
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
  public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
  {
    builder.Services.AddDatabases();
    builder.Services.AddExternals();
    builder.Services.AddUseCases();

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<HistoryLogMiddleware>();
  }
}

Testing the function, the domain class works fine (because the console shows...) but the middleware never registers on console or attach on debug mode.
My function:
public class RegisterClientFunction
{
  private readonly IClientsDomain _clientsDomain;

  public RegisterClientFunction(IClientsDomain clientsDomain)
  {
    _clientsDomain = clientsDomain;
  }

  [FunctionName(nameof(RegisterClientFunction))]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
  {
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegisterClientRequest>(requestBody);

    var resp = await ExecuterDomain.ExecuteAsync(() => _clientsDomain.RegisterClient(data));
    return new ObjectResult(resp);
  }
}

Does anybody know why the middleware isn't being invoked?


It seems like you haven't added your middleware to the execution pipeline. Here's how you can use it.
In your Program.cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(builder =>
    {
        builder.UseMiddleware<HistoryLogMiddleware>();
    })
    .Build();


but in azure functions project i cannot use : app.UseMiddleware();

I had to change from in-process to isolated. In the model in-process middleware isn't supported

The worker used wasn't stated in your questions so I was assuming that you are using isolated worker. My apologize for not stating my answer clearly previously, the app in app.UseMiddleware<HistoryLogMiddleware>(); is referring to the use of IFunctionsWorkerApplicationBuilder interface, I have updated the answer.
